# mongo-hadoop integration issue

Tags: git, mongodb, hadoop, bigdata

I am trying to integrate Hadoop and Mongo. I downloaded the mongo-hadoop files from git and trying to built jar files by using below. But i'm getting below error

```
[krishna@localhost mongo-hadoop]$ ./gradlew jar –Phadoop_version='2.4'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/krishna/mongo-hadoop/build.gradle' line: 318

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'mongo-hadoop'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':spark:compile'.
> Could not download artifact 'commons-math3.jar  (org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.4.1)'
  > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.4.1/commons-math3-3.4.1.jar'.
     > Network is unreachable

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

can anyone tell how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My firewall was blocking the connection. So i disabled the firewall and restarted the VM. Now it's working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that have network connection?

Try this in console for check if network is OK:

$ wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.4.1/commons-math3-3.4.1.jar